# Vector Math and Directional Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Short and sweet.

How does one calculate a directional vector in 3 dimensions by knowing the magnitude of the vector and the rotations about both the x and y axis?

Comment: Check out [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), specifically SS 3.1.

Comment: Ok so I read that (thanks for responding :D), and I am a bit confused as to what they are saying theta and alpha are in that section.  Actually, a lot confused.  Where do the rotations about the axis come into account anywhere in there? Additionally, do I even have the information I need to use those formulas?

Comment: What apecifically do you mean by *rotations*? You would usually rotate a known vector by an angle about an axis? By rotation, do you mean angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the assumption of my comment, that your *rotations* are the angle between the $x-$ and $y-$axes, you can find the vector with the following hints.

**Hints**
Let the vector being determined be $\vec{u}=[u_x,u_y,u_z]^T$.

1. It follows that $\|\vec{u}\|^2=u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2$.
2. You also have $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{i}=u_x=\|\vec{u}\|\cos\left(\theta_x\right)$.
3. Furthermore, you have $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{j}=u_y=\|\vec{u}\|\cos\left(\theta_y\right)$.

You now have 3 equations with 3 unknowns, as $\|\vec{u}\|,\,\theta_x$ and $\theta_y$ are known.

**Note:** This vector will **not** be unique.